# Сайт сервис react, админка, общий вопрос

Tags: wordpress, reactjs

Делаю сайт сервис с объявлениями на react + firebase, регистрация, кабинет, чат пользователей, заведение пользователями объявлений.

По реакту все понятно.

Не очень понимаю, как лучше вести сайт. Например, добавлять, редактировать статьи или страницы.

Например, в WordPress все понятно: админка, все дела. А как на реакте - через код? Или делать самому админку или прикручивать CMS? Да и для CMS под реакт общей инфы не нашел.

А если WordPress + React? У нас WP стоит на отдельном домене, и туда, допустим, обращается приложение на реакте?

Comment: Для Реакта нет разницы кто будет редактировать данные в БД. Главное знать АПИ, которое будет те данные возвращать. Если такое АПИ есть, Реакт будет получать от него данные и отрисовывать на клиенте

Comment: В WordPress есть REST API: https://wp-kama.ru/handbook/rest. Общаться с сайтом приложение на React должно через него.